# serverless express/jade website on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, web, pug, aws-api-gateway

I am new to serverless, and try to build a simple express website on AWS with lambda and api gateway.

The site runs successfully on my local, but after deploying to AWS, there is a issue about jade route as AWS gives a stage name to deployed API, for example: the root(/) url is something like - https://opl3cla000.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod(the prod is stage name). While in my jade layout.jade, I have code like

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav
  li
    a(href="/page1") Page1
  li
    a(href="/page2") Page2
```

My jade code does not include the stage name, so it gives 403 as the path is https://opl3cla000.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/prod/page1 instead of https://opl3cla000.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/page1.

I am not sure if it is the correct configuration, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can probably add a `<base href>` tag to your template.

Answer (score 2):

I use the middleware from awslabs/aws-serverless-express and get the answer from the author.

The reference link is below:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express/issues/11

Comment: This is a link only answer